# How to access the iterating-index in a sapUI5 Aggregation Binding?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In sapUI5 I have a JSONModel containing

```
{
  "element1": {
    "columnName": "col1",
    "values":[
      {"name": "value 1 - 1", "selected": true},
      {"name": "value 1 - 2", "selected": true},
      {"name": "value 1 - 3", "selected": true},
      {"name": "value 1 - 4", "selected": true}
    ]
  },
  "element2": {
    "columnName": "col2",
    "values":[
      {"name": "value 2 - 1", "selected": true},
      {"name": "value 2 - 2", "selected": true},
      {"name": "value 2 - 3", "selected": true},
      {"name": "value 2 - 4", "selected": true}
    ]
  }
}
```

and a XML-View bound to this model iterating over each element and each elements value (to display a checkbox for each value):

```
<mvc:View
    ...
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
    xmlns="sap.m"
>
    <VBox items="{/}">
        <VBox items="{values}">
            <CheckBox 
                text={name}
                app:xxColumName="{/columnName}" <!-- this is null - how to add columnName here? -->
            ></CheckBox>
        </VBox>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```

How can I access & bind the `columnName` value from the JSON-element to each checkbox?

Is there a syntax like `{/$idex/columnName}` so I can 'break out' of the 2nd loops namespace?

**Edit:**
[JS-Bin is here.](https://jsbin.com/humadoxuto/edit?html,output)

Comment: Your outer JSON structure is not an array but an object (thats why it's wrapped in `{}` and not `[]`). Are you sure you are iterating over anything?

Comment: Yepp. You can iterate over both: arrays and objects

Comment: Would be cool if you could set up a JSBin example.

Comment: Ok, I added a JS-Bin (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

One of the challenges is that the `items` aggregation binding you're introducing in the inner `VBox` imposes a context on the relative bindings in the template.

While not addressing your specific question directly (I don't think there is such a think as a sort of `$index` reference), I would suggest that as it's a `JSONModel` based data set, you can take the approach of munging the data to your requirements.

In other words, why not add the `columnName` property to each map in the `values` array?

Here's an example of how that might be done:

```
function addProp(p, v) { return function(m) { m[p] = v; return m; }; }
var mData = oModel.getData();
for (var e in mData) {
  mData[e].values = mData[e].values.map(addProp('columnName', mData[e].columnName));
}
oModel.setData(mData);
```

Add this just before this part:

```
myView.setModel(oModel);
myView.placeAt('content');
```

And you're done.

[image]

Comment: Useful, thanks. I solved my problem in a similar approach. Disadvantage is that this is a huge overhead of data in my model. Note that you can simplify your code in the loop to `oModel.setProperty("/" + e + "/columnName", mData[e].columnName);`. This way you dont have to `oModel.setData(mData);` after the loop - in case you store other data in the model.

Comment: yes, you could. But I wanted to keep the munging and the setting separate, mostly to illustrate the approach of modifying the data, that was all :-)